# Is it possible to set a default path/ direction for a conda environment once activating it?

Tags: directory, path, conda, default

I am looking for a method to go to a directory (by default) after activating a conda environment. In other words, I am just lazy enough to use an addition command "cd".

I have tried to google for a while but seems that most of the answers online are teaching people setting a default path for "storing/ creating" the conda environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this via an [activation script](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#saving-environment-variables):

```bash
## activate 'foo' environment
conda activate foo

## ensure activation script path exists
mkdir -p ${CONDA_PREFIX}/etc/conda/activate.d

## create script for 'cd bar'
echo 'cd bar' > ${CONDA_PREFIX}/etc/conda/activate.d/cd_to_bar.sh
```

A more sophisticated approach might also save the current working directory and switch back to it via a deactivation script (see [documentation](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#saving-environment-variables)).